# modprobe mwifiex doesn't support Marvell 8786's USB version, but the SDIO

Tags: wifi, configuration, usb-device

I needed a small (in-home) Access Point and remembered having saved a Marvell K20326 with an 88W8786U. After some research, I found that the `mwifiex` driver was the one indicated, which I 'insmod'ed successfully. It also called (and found) cfg80211. `Dmesg` detected the device:

```
[974038.223967] usb 1-2.3: new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
[974038.407437] usb 1-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1286, idProduct=203c, bcdDevice=31.14
[974038.407443] usb 1-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[974038.407446] usb 1-2.3: Product: Marvell Wireless Device
[974038.407449] usb 1-2.3: Manufacturer: Marvell
[974038.407452] usb 1-2.3: SerialNumber: 0000000000000000
```

Idem with `ifconfig`, and any other command I could find.

**Edit** Ok, well, over the last couple of days, I learned a lot. And found a lot of contradicting information. Digging into the kernel code, it seems that th `mwifiex` driver does *not* support the USB version of the 88W8786, but it *does* support the `SDIO` version.

So, rephrasing the issue:

Does anyone have any idea, how complicated it would be to convert the SDIO version to USB? And the probability that this could work?

And then there's the (closed) firmware issue.

Here are a couple of images of the board - there seem to be a lot of variants circulating, some with the same FCC codes.

[image: RF side of the board]
[image: Ground side of the board]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already found https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211497 where the last comment seems to introduce (part of) a solution.
Jumping here https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/Mwifiex#Drivers and here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git provides some more drivers.

Let's work on a solution for both our sakes.
I took apart an old Epson printer to transform this card into a USB wifi adapter with some simple soldering. Which indeed seems to be very possible, according to the FCC test setup we see here https://fccid.io/BKMFBSP88W8786/Test-Setup-Photos/TSup-BKMFBSP88W8786-1197293

With the soldering in place and a simple `$ lsusb` I was able to detect my device as ;

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1286:203c Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. K30326 802.11bgn Wireless Module [Marvell 88W8786U]
```

This was on two different machines running POP_OS. On a VMware Windows10 machine it was however only recognized as an adapter, but the machine was unable to install the proper drivers. So could you test if you experience a similar issue?
(I notice you mention a K20326, whereas I am working on a K30326. But I assume it wil work quite similar)

For the '*Pics or it didn't happen*' people out there
[image: Receiver side]
[image: Back side]

**Edit 01/2022**

Doing a bit of measuring whilst connected to desktop it is clear that the card has no internal regulator.

The throughput is a whopping 4.42 Volt!
I guess it is time to solder on some resistors.

@jcoppens Do you have a link to the experimenter you mention in your comment of 07-01-2022?

[image: Volt measurement]

**edit 06-03-2023**

Some small additions.
I added two diodes to bring down the voltage and two capacitors (1uF red+white wires and 110nF red wires) for cleaning. The resulting voltage on the card is 3.30V, 3.46V and 3.57V on different USB ports. This is the best I can manage for now.

Strangely enough, with this simpler setup the card is no longer detected via lsusb. The LM317 method, though more complex and quite messy, did result in a proper identification. (I never exposed it to any other power source but USB, so it seems unlikely I got it to a fried-state.)

[image: card with diodes]

Comment: I will investigate some more, but I have the impression that none of the firmwares provided for the Linux kernels support the 8786 chip. And there seem to be quite a few differences between chip architectures, even with similar numbers. Also your board is different from mine. Do check if you need a 3.3V regulator or not (mine does!) I suspect there is a regulator near the top of your board, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Added a couple of pictures of the module I have here (only the bar code label is formatted differently). Do check if you need a 3.3V regulator. One experimenter found that though it seemed to work at 5V (it identified on USB), it started working correctly only at 3.3V

Comment: Hmm... on [link]https://fccid.io/BKMFBSP88W8786/Users-Manual/UserMan-BKMFBSP88W8786-revised-2-1197294 it does mention "This module is powered from the host (3.3V) and interfaces to the host with USB2.0 signals.". So this 3.3V regulator may be needed after all.. Though I also remember reading about an internal regulator in one of the many documents

Comment: I can't identify the comment you are referring to. I suspect it's the link to the 3.3V problem. Check [this thread][https://alexkaltsas.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/hacking-a-printerss-wifi-module/], and search for `Craig N`: 'The voltage regulator, or rather, a 3.3V current is absolutely necessary for the HP modules.'

Comment: Thank you, I indeed found that one last week. I have brought down the voltage with an LM317 and some home made resistors (using SMD's, which was.. interesting). I will update my post to reflect the current workings. All that is still missing is the driver. I plan to send it across the borders, where it will be used on a W10 machine. So getting a lead on those drivers is most prevalent for me right now.

Comment: 'All that is still missing is the driver'... The driver is relatively simple - the other drivers have source code. The main problem is the firmware code corresponding to the usb8786. I've done a few more searches, but found nothing yet. If I'm not mistaken, Marvell's Wifi section was sold off to NXP now, which may make things even more complicated.

Comment: For some reason it won't install on a W10 virtual machine though. I suspect it may be fried somewhere, since the voltage is pretty wobbly across several USB-ports. Since my objective differs from your specific situation I hope someone else will stumble across this forum and add the missing link ; )

Comment: I suspect that the W10 driver detects that the (correct) firmware for the card is not available and will not install. In case of Linux, the driver starts, and does not work (even though started) because it doesn't have the correct firmware either. Only thing that is strange is that I can't find  any indication in the log files though.

Comment: this definitely needs more help from someone knowledgeable about that part then... I will still update some pics&info in the main post. srry for lag..